# Is there third party package tool with .NET4 support?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, installation

I got a C# program based on .NET4 environment. I want to make a installer which will ship .NET4 environment with it so that my user won't bother to install .NET4 indepently. Is there any third party package tool available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to install .Net Framework.

There was an example script in the below website.

http://zerosandtheone.com/media/p/180.aspx

Comment: is inno setup stupid enough to allow me just click here and there to create a diserable installer?